# Remove duplicates from groupBy

Tags: laravel

I would like to find out how many `Users` have `Swipes` per day without duplicates of `user_id` within group.
So if a `User` has swiped multiple times on a day, I want the `User` only show once per group (per day). I am not really interested in the actual `Swipes` but rather in the `swipe count` per day.

I tried:

`Swipe::all()->groupBy(function($item){ return $item->created_at->format('d-M-y'); })->unique('user_id')`

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicate data, you can use `unique()`.

I create an example for you.
I have dummy data like

[image: this].

So you want the result is data grouped by created_at and on every date return how many users swipe it but without duplicate user?

The code should be like:

```
    $collect = Swipe::all()->groupBy(function($data){
        return $item->created_at->format('d-M-y');
    })->transform(function($dataGrouped,$date){
        return [
            $date => $dataGrouped->unique('user_id')
        ];
    });
```

The result will be like:

[image]